# How to parse an XML file containing special characters

Tags: python, xml, parsing, special-characters

I am trying to parse XML files that contain special characters as `&`, `"`, `'`, `<` or `>` in the data. I would like to know how to do it properly.

NB: the files are quite huge and I do not have the hand on them to modify them. So I am looking for an automated way to transform the file before parsing it, such as using regular expressions or other stuff like them.

Answer (score 0):

Are these well-formed XML files or ill-formed XML files?

If they are ill-formed then you can't use an XML parser to process them. You will need to determine exactly how the data format differs from well-formed XML and write custom parsing code to handle the precise situations that occur in your data.

It might be difficult. For example if your file contains

```
<expr>a<b<c</expr>
```

then working out which `<` symbols are markup and which are data requires some serious analysis (or guesswork). And in the general case, the task is impossible.

Of course standards are there for a reason and it's far better if the person creating the data files reads the spec and follows it. That's the only way to do it "properly".